# Como selecionar e imprimir um valor dentro de uma lista criada por um "def"

Tags: python, python-3.x

O título já é auto explicativo, como eu faço para selecionar e escolher determinado **str** ou **int/float** dentro de uma lista que foi criada pela minha função registro

```
def registro(cadastroaluno):
    matricula = input("Número de Matrícula: ")
    telefone = input("Número de Telefone: ")
    endereco = input("Endereço: ")
    respReg = matricula,telefone,endereco
    return respReg

aluni = str
print(registro(aluni))
```

Por exemplo:

Como eu faço para selecionar o valor **'32'** localizada na linha **[2]** e imprimir ela logo após?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que função retorna não é uma lista, é um tuple (pensa nisso como uma lista imutável).

A tua variável `aluni`, pode deixar de existir, nesse pedaço de código não está a servir para nada.

Quanto à tua duvida porque não fazes assim:

```
def registro():
    matricula = input("Número de Matrícula: ")
    telefone = input("Número de Telefone: ")
    endereco = input("Endereço: ")
    return (matricula,telefone,endereco)

dados = registro() # dentro de dados tens todos os dados que foram introduzidos
print(dados[2])
```

Ou até podes fazer o unpacking do tuple que retorna para ficares com as variáveis em separado:

```
...
matricula, tele, endereco = registro()
print(endereco)
```

Se fores usar só mesmo o indice 2 e excluir os outros podes fazer logo:

```
def registro():
    matricula = input("Número de Matrícula: ")
    telefone = input("Número de Telefone: ")
    endereco = input("Endereço: ")
    return (matricula,telefone,endereco)

endereco = registro()[2]
print(endereco)
```

Lembra-te que os inputs retornam sempre strings, para os os converteres podes:

```
...
int(input("Endereço: "))
...
```

Comment: Não consegui atribuir dados ao registro ().
Poderia criar um código simples com o que você está tentando me dizer?

Comment: @KennethAnderson como assim atribuir os dados? Vou colocar por completo

Comment: Eu tinha falado errado, me desculpe, sou novato em Python. Eu estava falando que eu não tava conseguindo fazer com que "registro()" não conseguisse ser atribuído a "dados".
Consegui agora graças a você, obrigado!
P.S: Desculpa pelo comentário de explicação/agradecimento.

Comment: Não há problema nenum @KennethAnderson, ainda bem que ajudei